# Why does CodeQL not populate the CodeQL database with a Gradle build?

Tags: java, github, gradle, azure-devops, codeql

I have a repository that has a Java codebase that is built using Gradle. In the Azure DevOps pipeline for this application I am first running the following command to setup the CodeQL build tracing:

```
codeql database init --source-root Build.Repository.LocalPath --language java, --begin-tracing codeql-db --overwrite --db-cluster
```

This works successfully with the following output:

```
Resolving extractor java.
Successfully loaded extractor Java (java) from /apps/ado/tools/codeql/java.
Created skeleton CodeQL database at /apps/ado/vsts/agent2/_work/3335/codeql-db. This in-progress database is ready to be populated by an extractor.
```

I then set the tracing variables as environment variables.

The code is then built with Gradle.

Then I'm finalizing the database with:

```
codeql database finalize codeql-db
```

But the output is:

```
No source code was seen and extracted to /apps/ado/vsts/agent2/_work/3335/codeql-db.
This can occur if the specified build commands failed to compile or process any code.
- Confirm that there is some source code for the specified language in the project.
- For codebases written in Go, JavaScript, TypeScript, and Python, do not specify
   an explicit --command.
- For other languages, the --command must specify a "clean" build which compiles
   all the source code files without reusing existing build artefacts.
```

This same action works perfectly on a Maven build but I can't for the life of me see a reason why this isn't recognizing the compile. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the Gradle build already before you run it with CodeQL, or are you caching the build output in some way? If Gradle skips compilation because the output is already up to date, then I assume CodeQL will not see any classes. Could you try running Gradle with `--rerun-tasks`?

Comment: Also, maybe a bit naive question, but couldn't you just use `codeql database create codeql-db --language=java` (optionally with `--command ...`) as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/codeql-cli/getting-started-with-the-codeql-cli/preparing-your-code-for-codeql-analysis#running-codeql-database-create)? Do you really need to use these 'plumbing' commands `database init` and `database finalize`?

Comment: @Marcono1234 in this particular setup we are required to indirectly watch the compile. These are generic scripts. 1 script will setup the tracing and another script, run post compile, will finalize and analyze. This is my requirement as they need to be generic scripts that wrap around the build process for many different pipelines.

Comment: Ah ok. Have you tried using `--rerun-tasks` with your Gradle command though? At least to get some hint what might be causing this issue, even if for your desired end result you cannot permanently set `--rerun-tasks`.

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle, it is most common that a background process is handling the build.  Since CodeQL needs to trace the compiler invocations that happen to create its' database, you should disable the gradle daemon:

Checkout the sample from these CodeQL docs: "[Specifying build commands](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/codeql-cli/getting-started-with-the-codeql-cli/preparing-your-code-for-codeql-analysis#specifying-build-commands)".

> ## Use `--no-daemon` because a build delegated to an existing daemon cannot be detected by CodeQL.
>
> ## To ensure isolated builds without caching, add `--no-build-cache` on persistent machines.

`codeql database create java-database --language=java-kotlin --command='gradle --no-daemon --no-build-cache clean test'`